# JodaTime Hibernate support saving DateTime with wrong TimeZone

Tags: java, hibernate, timezone, jodatime

I know there are similar questions out there but I wanted to be clear on exactly what the problem is.

Basically I am trying to save a date in my Oracle database. I want it to be stored in UTC time. The column in the database is a TIMESTAMP, I'm not saving the TimeZone info.

Looking at the JodaTime Hibernate support class PersistentDateTime, it seems the nullSafeGet() method is simply calling DateTime.toDate(), which returns a java.util.Date. That's the date that's saved in the database.

What I don't get is ... why doesn't getDate() preserve the TimeZone of the existing DateTime? I send it a DateTime (say 17:00) in UTC and upon calling getDate() it's switched to my TimeZone, CET (18:00). I want it to save 17:00, not 18:00.

I realize this is (probably) getting the TimeZone from the environment I am running Java in, and that one possibility is changing that with a command line parameter. But I don't want to do that, plus I'm not allowed to on the production machine anyway.

My current idea is to implement a class that extends PersistentDateTime and override the nullSafeGet() method, so it maintains the TimeZone of the DateTime that is passed to it. Not sure exactly how to do that ... perhaps there's a method in the JodaTime api somewhere that does this elegantly?

Anyway, I was just curious if anyone else is surprised by this behavior or if it's just me. And if my idea is a good one or if someone has a better one. Changing the servers (application or database) or other configuration is not an option, I need to fix this with code.

**EDIT**

For posterity's sake, and to reply to the helpful commenters, I'd like to clarify exactly what my problem was/is.

I thought the problem was that my app server and my db server had different time zones. This turns out to not have been the problem. The problem is rather that the app server, or JVM, has a different time zone than the one I am using in my app. Let me explain.

My web app manages Events. Events have a start and end date. These are TIMESTAMP columns (without time zone) in the Oracle database. Furthermore, within the app you must define what time zone you are using. This is irregardless of the time zone that the app server (and subsequently the JVM) or db server are using.

But of course the app server ***does*** have a time zone. In my case it is CST, Central Standard Time (GMT-6). The problem arises when the time zone used in the app does not coincide with the one used at the JVM level. In my case the time zone defined in the app is EST, Eastern Standard Time (GMT-5).

So what's happening? What's happening is, I create an Event from the web admin panel with, for example:

- Start date: January 15th, 2014 09:00
- End date:   January 20th, 2014 23:00

These dates are created using Joda DateTime and are assigned the *proper* time zone (using DateTime.withZoneRetainFields()), namely, the one I am using in the application, EST. So my Event looks like this:

- Event Name: Event 1
- Start date: 15/01/2014 09:00 EST
- End date:   20/01/2014 23:00 EST

So far so good. When I save it, however, the dates are saved as follows:

- Start date: 15/01/2014 08:00
- End date:   20/01/2014 22:00

What happened? What happened was since the app server/JVM is running in CST, it subtracted an hour from both dates. I thought it was a bug but as suggested by commenters, it's a feature. The JodaTime Hibernate drivers simply call DateTime.toDate() which creates a java.util.Date, which itself does not have a time zone but which does automatically change the hour according to the time zone being used by the JVM.

How can I avoid this? Well, I could start the JVM with the -Duser.timezone parameter, and make sure it is always the same as the time zone being used in the application. That's one option.

Another thing I could do is instead of avoiding the problem, work with it. In other words, at the Hibernate/database level, whenever I load an Event, make sure the start and end date fields are assigned the app-defined time zone, and thus have the hours converted back to the time zone used in the application. That way, even though they are saved as 08:00 and 22:00, they would be displayed as 09:00 and 23:00 in the application. This is obviously the better solution and more explicit. But I'm just not sure if it's worth all the work. I've seen various ways to do this with Hibernate on the web -- using Property Access Type or a custom Hibernate User Type. Not sure if they work properly or not and it seems like a lot of work and very intrusive. I have to change from using DateTime to Calendar (I think, not sure) and/or make special mappings in my POJO.

The truth is we have java.util.Dates all over the app and in many cases simply do a new Date() to instantiate them, without taking into consideration the time zone. These should all eventually be changed to DateTime and be explicitly instantiated using the app-defined time zone.

But that's a lot of work. For the time being I've opted to simply use the -Duser.timezone parameter, and see how it goes. Again, not the best solution, but I think it serves our needs for now.

Many thanks to all commenters for "opening my eyes" as it were.

Comment: Code. We need *code*. (And the answer is almost certainly that the date is being internally stored as an offset from the epoch and just interpreted on load or displayed in your local timezone.)

Answer (score 1):

### j.u.Date Is Tricky

Comment by chrylis is most likely correct: You are being fooled by the java.util.Date class. A Date has no time zone, yet its `toString` implementation applies your JVM's default time zone. So to the inexperienced Java programmer, it *seems* like the Date object has a time zone but in fact **does not**.

If chrylis and I are correct, then you do not have a database problem, you do not have a JDBC problem, you do not have a Hibernate problem, and you do not have a [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) problem. The problem is with the poorly designed and implemented java.util.Date/Calendar classes.

Another possible explanation is similar… A Joda-Time [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) instance does truly know its assigned time zone. If you neglect to assign a time zone, the JVM's **default time zone will be assigned**. Alternatively, specify a time zone object ([DateTimeZone](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html) class) such as the predefined constant [`DateTimeZone.UTC`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#UTC) object.

**Upshot:** You probably have no problem or bug at all. Just misunderstood features.

### Homework…

Bundled Java classes…

```java
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
long dateMillis = date.getTime();
```

Joda-Time…  (Convert that java.util.Date instance)

```java
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( date, DateTimeZone.UTC );     
long dateTimeMillis = dateTime.getMillis();
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "date: " + date + " = " + dateMillis );
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime + " = " + dateTimeMillis );
```

When run…

```
date: Sat Jan 25 17:18:02 PST 2014 = 1390699082010
dateTime: 2014-01-26T01:18:02.010Z = 1390699082010
```

Comment: Right you both are. The one thing I was missing was comparing the results of getTime() from my java.util.Date with getMillis() from my Joda DateTime. If I had done that I would have seen they were the same instant. The problem I am having, it seems, is that the TimeZone settings, both for the web server and database server, are different for my test environment, the QA environment, pre-production and production. It's a mess. But it seems the problem is at the JDBC level; if I can **always** assume that the web server is running in the same TZ (be it GMT, CET, etc) it will save consistently.

Comment: @RobertBowen On the contrary, I recommend you **always specify a time zone** rather than rely on defaults. If you specify, then it does not matter to which location/time zone your server is set. You only need to assume the server's clock is set to the correct time for its assigned time zone. And even this I don't assume; in my startup and maintenance routines I call a trusted local [time server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_server) or one over the internet and compare to the server's clock. See [DateTimeZone class](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html).

Comment: By "always use a Time Zone" do you mean saved in the bd with the Date/Timestamp data? We don't have TZ fields in the db, and can't add them unfortunately. So if my Linux box/Java has TZ CST but within the app the user also selects what TZ they want to use (eg CET), when I save a new DateTime, say 11am CET, it's saved 4am. So when I load it from the db, by default it will be 4am CET. To display it properly and do calculations I need to assign the app TZ (CET) making it 11am again. So while relying on default TZ is bad, having to manually change the TZ for every db load isn't great either no?

Comment: I just realized that in my first post I didn't mention the concept of the app-level TZ. Sorry about that. I was convinced my problem was the different TZs between the web and db server. But now I know the problem is having the Linux/JVM TZ different from the app TZ. If they are the same, the date is saved just as it's displayed in the app. If not, the date is re-calculated using the JVM TZ and saved. Anyway, I suppose I could do some kind of Hibernate class that automatically changes the date to the app TZ when loading, but I don't know if it's worth it ... Anyway, thanks for all your help.

Comment: I'm a Postgres guy, not Oracle, so I'm not sure but according to [this doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i54330) if you are truly using TIMESTAMP type code 180, then that's okay as long as you are 100% sure that all entry points into Oracle (all pieces of all apps, all command-line use, etc.) are converting date-time values to UTC/GMT values on insertions and updates. Your JDBC driver may be helping you with that, read the driver's doc. Ditto for Hibernate (which I don't use).

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "app TZ". But if you or your sysadmins have proper control of your systems, you should be able to set your OS time zone to a real one without screwing things up. Usually a server's OS tz is set to UTC/GMT (or "Atlantic/Reykjavik"), but as an app developer I *never* want to depend on sysadmin doing the right thing. You should know and take control of what your app, JDBC driver, Hibernate, and database are all doing with your data. Within your Java app, you should always be explicitly setting time zone on Joda-Time (or java.time.*) objects.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is basically found inside the JDBC driver, which tries to transform dates to/from the current JVM timezone as @RobertBowen said. There are several ways to find a workaround for this problem as already have been commented above (using UTC). However, I leave you two possible immediate solutions (although not best practices).

1.- When starting the JVM set the value:

> -Duser.timezone parameter

2.- When your application starts up, set the desired TimeZone: `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Mexico/General"));`